# execute git blame command in java

Tags: java, linux, git, github

I'm trying to use the following Java syntax to execute a Git blame command:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/git blame https://github.com/git/git/alloc.c > TestGit.txt");
```

But, when I run the code in Java, it doesn't give any result. And, when I tried to execute it in the Terminal, it just creates an empty "TestGit.txt" file, and I got the error: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the right syntax to execute blame command in Java for linux:

```
git --git-dir=/home/gh/git/.git --work-tree=/home/gh/git blame builtin/tag.c
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to change directories into the git repository prior to launching the command

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /path/to/repository; /usr/bin/git blame https://github.com/git/git/alloc.c > TestGit.txt");
```

Comment: @caarlos0 Either you are not on a Linux / Unix system, or your shell has the command `cd` built-in.  If the latter, try launching `/bin/bash -c` with the rest of the command as the "input string".

Answer (score 0):

I think for `git blame` to work, you'll need to be *inside* the repository.  You'd need to be inside the repository directory (which means you'll need to check it out first), and run:

```
git blame alloc.c
```

Comment: ya when I use the "cd" command to go inside "git" folder. Then, I use "git blame alloc.c" in the terminal, it works. However, I need to execute the blame command on the on-line file. But, it didn't work

Comment: You can't use git blame against an online file in the way you're doing; you have to check out the repository first.

Comment: OK, I cloned it to my computer. But now, when I use the "cd" command to be inside the directory (git), and then apply "blame" command, it works. However, when I use the path of the file "git blame /home/gh/git", I get the same error???

Answer (score 0):

The javier way:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/git blame https://github.com/git/git/alloc.c > TestGit.txt", null, new File('/path/to/repository'));
```